# Is there a parallel tangent to this surface?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I am struggling with this question. Given a vector field $F(x,y,z)$ and a surface $z = S(x, y)$.

> Is there a tangent plane of $S$ that is parallel to $F$ (anywhere)?

For example $F(x, y, z) = (-x^3, -x - y, z)$ and $S(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$.

My attempt is first to get the tangent plane of $S$. The plane equation:

$$
z - z_0 = S_x(x_0, y_0)(x - x_0) + S_y(x_0, y_0)(y - y_0)
$$

Gradient:

$$
S_x(x, y) = 2x
$$
$$
S_y(x, y) = 2y
$$

So that is

$$
z - z_0 = 2 x_0 (x - x_0) + 2 y_0 (y - y_0)
$$
$$
q(x, y, z) = (-2x_0) x + (-2y_0) y + z = (z_0 - 2x_0^2 - 2y_0^2)
$$

Again gradient:

$$
F_x = q_x \rightarrow -3x^2=-2x_0
$$
$$
F_y = q_y \rightarrow -1 = -2y_0
$$
$$
F_z = q_z \rightarrow 1 = 1
$$

So my answer would be that there is a tangent plane at $x = 2/3, y = 1/2$ ($z$ doesn't matter).

1. Is this done right?
2. Can I treat the $x_0$ and the $x$ like the same variable because I want to check all $x_0$? I am not sure because the $S_x(x_0, y_x)(x - x_0)$ would then be $0$ if $x_0 = x$.
3. Do I have to insert $z = S(x, y)$ in $F(x, y, z) = F(x, y, S(x, y))$?

Comment: It's not clear why you are differentiating the components of $F$. Also, it's not clear: Is the question, "Is there a point $a \in S$ and a point $b \in \Bbb R^3$ such that the tangent space $T_a S$ is parallel to $X_b$ (under the usual identification of tangent spaces in $\Bbb R^n$)?", or is the question "Is there a point $a \in S$ such that $X_a$ is parallel to (and thus contained in) $T_a S$?"

Comment: (There are a couple of other plausible interpretations, too, but they seem less likely.)

Comment: @TravisWillse I want to check when I am moving around on $S$ if I am at some point moving in the same direction that $F$ points.

Comment: Hm, that explanation reads just as ambiguously to me. Putting my latter suggested interpretation another way, do you mean, "Is there a point $a \in S$ such that $X_a \in T_a S$, i.e., do you mean "...if I am at some point $a$, moving in the same direction as $F_a$ (the value of $F$ at the point $a$)", or can the direction you are moving be parallel to the value $F_b$ of $F$ at some other point $b$?

Comment: @TravisWillse The direction can be parallel to $F_b$.

Comment: (In the above $X_a$ should be $F_a$.)

Comment: In fact in either case the answer is yes, since $F_{(0, 0, 0)} = (0, 0, 0)$, which is parallel to the tangent space $T_{(0, 0, 0)} {\bf S}$, where $\bf S$ is the given surface, $\{(x, y, S(x, y)) : (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2\}$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes means my approach is correct?

Comment: Again it's not clear why you're differentiating the components of $F$---those give you rates of change of the vector field in different directions, which are not immediately relevant to your problem.

Comment: @TravisWillse That is part of the question, I am not sure how to do this correctly... Should I just use$F(x, y, S(x, y))$? But how can I check then if this is parallel to the plane?

Comment: Once you've seen that the above example at $(0, 0, 0)$ satisfies your condition, you're done with the problem.

Comment: @TravisWillse Ok but can you help me seeing it? Where do I have to look or which terms do I have to equate. How do you know $(0,0,0)$ is right?

Comment: The zero vector is parallel to everything, so if we can find a point $(x, y, z)$ where $F(x, y, z) = 0$, we're done. Writing this in components immediately forces $x = z = 0$, and then $y = 0$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Ok, so the zero vector is special I didn't knew that it is parallel to everything. But what to do if we exclude the zero vector?

Comment: I've written an answer describing how to find a general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments under the question, we're looking for points $(u, v, w) \in \Bbb R^3$ and $(x, y, z) \in {\bf S}$ such that $$F_{(u, v, w)} \parallel T_{(x, y, z)} {\bf S} .$$
Here, we denote by $\bf S$ the surface $\{(x, y, S(x, y)) : (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2\}$.

This holds iff $F_{(u, v, w)}$ is orthogonal to a nonzero vector normal to $S$ at $(x, y, z)$. Since $\bf S$ is the level set $G^{-1}(0)$ of $$G(x, y, z) = z - S(x, y) = - x^2 - y^2 + z ,$$
one such normal vector at $(x, y, z) \in {\bf S}$ is $\nabla G (x, y, z) = (-2 x, -2 y, 1)$.

Thus we can write the orthogonality condition as
$$F_{(u, v, w)} \cdot \nabla G(x, y, z) = 0 ,$$
or substituting,
$$(-u^3, -u - v, w) \cdot (-2 x, -2 y, 1) = 0$$
This is a single equation in five variables, and so generically we expect solutions to depend on four parameters.

**Remark** It's perhaps more interesting to ask for points $(x, y, z)$ where $F_{(x, y, z)} \parallel T_{(x, y, z)} {\bf S}$, which amounts to specializing the above equation to $u = x, v = y, w = z = x^2 + y^2$, leaving a single equation in two variables.